# How to share a python program as an executable?

Tags: python, git, github

I wrote a Python program with GUI built using `tkinter`. I want to share my project as an open-source software in Git. My goal was to enable the end-user to download/clone my repository and run an executable present in it.

So I made my Python file to an executable using `pyinstaller`. I then pushed all the files created by the `pyinstaller` *(ex: dist, build files)* to [my repository](https://github.com/maddypie/Bin2Dec). Is this the correct way to distribute a software?

Though I wrote my software only using Python, the files created by `pyinstaller` dominated the result:

[image]

Furthermore, when I tried cloning my repository the executable present in it throws an error, though the executable I created originally works without any problem.

[image]

I used the flag `--onefile` to create the executable using `pyinstaller`. Someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be getting blocked, I would recommend creating a release in Github and archive the executable so others can download it from there or you can just archive the executable. Not sure if Github blocks plain executables or not but is safer to just archive it into a .zip or a .rar, or .tar file.

Comment: Thank you so much. I archived the executable and created a release in git. Now it works.

Comment: Awesome, I am glad to be able to help.